# Output the vowels and consonants of a string (without imports or for/while loops)

Tags: python

The code I currently have requires me to input all the vowels or consonants, I don't think this is very efficient. As of now, I'm not allowed to use `map` or `for` in my code because I'm on chapter 2 of python (this covers lists, slicing..)

```py
phrase = input("Phrase: ")

num_words = len(phrase.split(" "))

num_vowels = (
    phrase.count("a")
    + phrase.count("e")
    + phrase.count("i")
    + phrase.count("o")
    + phrase.count("u")
)

num_consonants = len(phrase.replace(" ", "")) - num_vowels

num_char = len(phrase)


print(f"words: {num_words}")
print(f"vowels : {num_vowels}")
print(f"consonants: {num_consonants}")
print(f"chars: {num_char}")
```

I'm wondering if there's an optimized way of accomplishing this on the level I currently am at programming.

Comment: I don't think there's a simpler way with your limitations.

Comment: No `for` loops and no `importing` is a heavy restriction. Any way of dynamically doing this would require some sort of iteration over your `vowels` (either done explicitly by you or inside another module/library).

Comment: Without looping or importing, I think that this is very good

Comment: Don't worry yourself too much about 'optimizing' your code this early in the game. Learn more methods as you go and eventually the optimization techniques will come to you.

Comment: Okay, so I'm guessing this would have been "wrong" if I chose the consonants instead as they're much more than vowels right?

Comment: Correct. I took a C# course long ago, even tho the syntax is not very similar, the first thing that came up my mind was storing the vowels/consonants on a list/array. Then ask whether any of those elements(letters) where part of the phrase string (after deleting the spaces between the words and merging them all into one big single word)

Comment: Can you use `while` loops?

Comment: Can you use list comprehensions? `num_vowels = len([x for x in phrase if x in 'aeiou'])`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the comments - your code is fine. But I also hear you, you didn't get into python to manually write phrase.count() five times! python is supposed to be simple and concise even at a starting level.

A suggestion of an alternate way you could do the same thing would be list comprehension:

```
num_vowels = sum([phrase.count(each_vowel) for each_vowel in 'aeiou'])
```

Now I don't know if that is cheating (there is a "for" loop fairly prominent inside the list comprehension) - maybe one of the many, many more experienced programmers could comment. But if you are starting I really recommend you spend some time learning the tricks to list comprehension - it goes a long way making your code more concise.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use packages, re will do the trick:

```
import re

num_vowels = len(re.findall('[aeiouAEIOU]+', phrase))
```

If you're only allowed to use base python, then this is a barely cleaner (but functionally not different) way to print:

```
print("words: " + str(num_words),'\n' + "vowels: " + str(num_vowels), "\n" + "consonants: " + str(num_consonants), '\n' + "chars: " + str(num_char))
```

Hope this helps!